# Tell Dojo to look for minified classes with ArcGIS JavaScript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

I've got an application build using the ArcGIS JavaScript API. I have several classes built with Dojo define. Each class is in a separate file, and everything is working fine.

However, I've minified my classes (using Visual Studio Web Essentials), and I'd like to tell Dojo to use the minified files. I'm using a dojoConfig like the following:

```
var dojoConfig = {
  isDebug: false,
  packages: [{
    name: 'js',
    location: '/js'
  }]
};
```

And dojo loads my files like '/js/MyClass.js'. What do I have to do the get Dojo to load MyClass.min.js ? This would be a successful resolution to my problem.

But, even more, I have gzipped versions of those files, so how can I tell Dojo to download MyClass.min.js.gzip?

I'd even like to take it a step further and bundle all of my classes into one download, say MyBundle.min.js.gzip. That not a problem. But, again, how to explain to the Dojo AMD loader that /js/MyClass1 and /js/MyClass2 are both in MyBundle?

All this, given that I'm not using the Dojo build system.

Answer (score 3):

I hate to answer my own question, but I've found a resolution. ESRI is releasing their JavaScript Web Optimizer, which will bundle and optimize everything into one file. That includes custom classes, Dojo itself, and only the required JavaScript API modules. I saw it at the Dev Summit, and it's pretty interesting.